# Strcmp trouble. Strings are no equal

Tags: php, string, strcmp

why its echo `1` ? this 2 strings are the same! `strcmp()` should be `0`! What's wrong? Can someone tell me why this two strings are NOT equal?

```
if(!strcmp("+7 (921) 111-11-11", "+7 (921) 111-11-11"))
    echo "1";
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/ngFU4 -> `0` -> `!0` -> `1`

Comment: remove "Not" `!` operator from condition clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp()` does evaluate to 0 in this case - But this leads to it being type juggled to false, and then to !false, so the original statement runs. Change it to this:

```
if (strcmp("+7 (921) 111-11-11", "+7 (921) 111-11-11") !== 0) 
    echo 1; // Strings are not equal
```